# Applying semicolon to the values in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

Currently I am working on an SQL script. The result of the script is a table with three columns.I want to apply a semicolon to the left side of all the values.

```
Select distinct
emp_id, -->numeric value
emp_dob, -- >numeric value
emp_ssid -- >alphnumeric value
.
.
```

How can I do it. I am quite new to SQL

Comment: This is invalid in Oracle. And if this were SQL Server, it would be absolutely nonsensical. You'd convert emp_id (which is probably a number) to a number? Using a date format (20)? Or is this still another DBMS? Please correct your DBMS tag.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : My bad. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  I have edited the tag and also my question. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, I think you want `||`:

```
Select distinct emp_id || ';', 
       emp_dob || ';' -- >numeric value
       emp_ssid, || ';' -- >alphnumeric value
```

Your syntax strongly suggests SQL Server, but the question is tagged Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Because you wanted to append a semicolon to the end of the value, your result column cannot be converted to a numeric value. You need to cast it to nvarchar and then append.

Please try
    CAST(emp_id AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ';'

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Now I have edited my question. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONVERT` to turn a numeric column into string. The string concatenation operator in Sybase is the non-standard `+`.

```
select 
  ';' + convert(varchar, emp_id),
  ';' + convert(varchar, emp_dob),
  ';' + emp_ssid
from ...
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks